# Adding author option to [products] woocommerce shortcode

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, author

I am trying to modify the [products] shortcode usage:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-11

What I am looking was passing the author id from short code e.g [products author=2] to the query.

With the reference of:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-special-product-attribute-to-the-products-shortcode/

But the sample was a true/false parameter to trigger the $query_args change, seems it's not exactly my goal. And the function below is the only part I can put into use.

```
function htdat_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $attributes ) {       
$query_args = array(
   //Receive the id//'author'    => '1',
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'post_type'      => 'product',
   'post_per_page'      => 12,
   );   
   
  return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'htdat_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 2 );
```

If anyone could help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
function htdat_shortcode_atts_products( $out, $pairs, $atts, $shortcode ) {
    if ( isset ( $atts['author'] ) ) $out['author'] = $atts['author'];
    return $out;
}
add_filter('shortcode_atts_products', 'htdat_shortcode_atts_products', 10, 4);

function htdat_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $attributes ) {       
    if ( isset( $attributes['author'] ) ) $query_args['author'] = $attributes['author'];
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'htdat_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: The output show all products from all authors. I think the $attributes['author'] is not getting right from shortcode before it passes to query?

Comment: @Cwkin7 Try to hardcode the author id: `$query_args['author'] = 2; return $query_args;` and check if it alters the output?

Comment: No change to the out put. I was looking back to the reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-special-product-attribute-to-the-products-shortcode/. There should be a shortcode_atts function to add up?

Comment: @Cwkin7 I added that one to the answer, but if the hardcoded author id doesn't changed the output I think that one won't solve the problem too. I'll give it a live test on one of my sites in a few hours to check what happens under the hood.

Comment: Yes, it's working, I combined them.
`function htdat_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $attributes ) { 
 
$query_args = array(
   'author'    => $attributes['author'],
   'post_status'    => 'publish',
   'post_type'      => 'product',
   'post_per_page'      => 12,
   );   
   
  return $query_args;
}`